# Angular Hashtag Rewrite - Html5Mode

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have html5mode enabled so my urls look like domain.com/route and not like domain.com/#/route.

What I use is this rewrite code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

It works fine with first level routes (domain.com/firstlevel) but it doesn't with secondlevel (domain.com/firstlevel/secondlevel).

Any ideas on how I can modify the rewrite code to put an "/#" before the whole url of any length?

Thanks

Comment: The first part of your Rule will take the entire URI so it should also include secondlevel. What exactly is happening?

Comment: Oh sorry, you're totally right. But still the view isn't loaded.. (templateUrl)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a code problem however it might be getting encoded and maybe that's why it's not working for you. Typically if you don't escape the `#` it will encode it.

You can try it using the `NE` flag.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [NE,L]
```